# Sum of all absolute values of difference of the numbers 1,2,.....n taken two at a time

Tags: summation

> The sum of all absolute values of the differences of the numbers $1,2,3,\ldots, n$, taken two at a time, i.e. $$\sum_{j\le i\le n}\left|i-j\right|$$ equals:
>
> (A) $\binom{n-1}3$  (B) $\binom n 3$  (C) $\binom{n+1}3$  (D)$\binom{n+2}3$

Please give me hints on starting off with this problem. Kindly **don't** put the whole answer.

([Original scan of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn5dW.jpg))

Comment: Why not work it out for some small values of $n$ to see which answer fits, then try to prove it?

Comment: @Gerry's suggestion lets us immediately rule out (A), (B) by considering $n=2$.

Comment: Of course I could do it because it is a multiple choice type question. But, I want to develop my problem solving ability even without the options. So, I want a hint on starting off the solution for this even if the options are not given.

Comment: In that case then try doing it like this. If you fix $j$ to be $1$ and let $i$ range from $1$ up to $n$, you get the numbers, $1,2,3,...,n-1$. Now let $j=2$ and let $i$ range from $2$ to $n$, you get the numbers $1,2,3,...,n-2$, and so on. You end up getting: $(1+...+(n-1))+(1+...+(n-2))+...+(1+2)+(1)$.

Comment: $$\begin{matrix}0&1&2&3&\dotsb\\1&0&1&2&\dotsb\\2&1&0&1&\dotsb\\3&2&1&0&\dotsb\\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\end{matrix}$$

Comment: If you are going to prescribe $j\leq i$ why use $|i-j|$? Isn't $|i-j|=i-j$ in that instance?

Comment: yeah that's right.......

Comment: If you want the differences taken two at a time, both $i$ and $j$ have to go from $1$ to $n$. That is what I have done in my solution.

Comment: My suggestion that you work it out for some small values of $n$ applies even if it's not multiple choice. You do examples, you make a guess as to the answer, then you try to prove it. If you fail, *then* you ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fix $j=1$, then let $i$ range you get: $1+2+..+(n-1)$.

If you fix $j=2$, then let $i$ range you get: $1+2+..+(n-2)$.

...

If you fix $j=n-1$, then let $i$ range you get: $1$.

If you put them all together you get a total of $(n-1)$ number of $1$'s, $(n-2)$ number of $2$'s,..., $1$ number of $(n-1)$'s. Thus your sum equals: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\cdot (n-k)$$Which equals: $n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^2$, and using the well know formulas (and some algebra) you get $n^3/6-n/6$, which is equal to $\binom{n+1}{3}$

Answer (score 2):

The sum of all absolute values of the differences of the numbers 1,2,3,…,n, taken two at a time is

$\begin{align}
S(n)
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n}|i-j|\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}|i-j|
+\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}|i-j|\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}(i-j)
+\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}(j-i)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}j
+\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n-i}j\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i(i-1)}{2}
+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(n-i)(n-i+1)}{2}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i(i-1)}{2}
+\frac{(n-i)(n-i+1)}{2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i(i-1)+(n-i)(n-i+1)}{2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i^2-i+(n-i)^2+(n-i)}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n\left(i^2-i+n^2-2ni+i^2+n-i\right)\\
&=\frac{n(n^2+n)}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^n\left(i^2-i-2ni\right)\\
&=\frac{n(n^2+n)}{2}+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-(2n+1)\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\left(n+\frac{(2n+1)}{3}-(2n+1)\right)\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)}{6}\left(3n+(2n+1)-3(2n+1)\right)\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)}{6}\left(3n-(2n+1)\right)\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)}{6}\left(n-1\right)\\
&=\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{6}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{3}\\
\end{align}
$

(Whew!)

There are probably simpler ways,
but this is my way.

Comment: It should be $2\binom{n+1}{3}$, is not so?

Comment: Not so. I believe my solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(n)=\sum_{1\le j\le i\le n}|i-j|$. Then $f(n+1)=f(n)+\sum_{1\le j\le n}|n-j|=f(n)+\sum_{0\le j\le n-1}j$.
You may know a formula for the latter sum and then make a suitable ansatz that can be shown by induction.

Comment: $f(n+1)$ contains a term of size $n$. It doesn't show up in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

First af all, the modulus is unnecessary as $i \ge j.$ Next, the sum $$ \sum_{j\le i\le n}(i-j)= \sum_{j=1}^{j=n}\sum_{i=j }^{i=n} (i-j).$$ The inner sum $$\sum_{i=j }^{i=n} (i-j)=\frac 1 2 (n+1)^2-\frac 1 2 n-\frac 1 2-j(n+1)+\frac 1 2 j^2+\frac 1 2 j .$$  Therefore, the sum under consideration equals $$\sum_{j=1}^{j=n}\left(\frac 1 2 (n+1)^2-\frac 1 2 n-\frac 1 2-j(n+1)+\frac 1 2 j^2+\frac 1 2 j \right)= \frac 1 6 (n^3-n) =C_{n+1}^{3}. $$

Answer (score 1):

After having seen @marty cohen 's answer I'd argue as follows:

The sum $S$ in question is equal to the number of unit intervals of the form
$$[l,l+1]\qquad (0\leq i-1<l<j\leq n)\ ,$$
counted with multiplicity. Each such interval determines a three-element subset of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of the form $\{i-1,l,j\}$ with $i-1<l<j\ $, and conversely: For any three-element subset $\{i-1,l,j\}$ of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$ we obtain an interval $[l,l+1]\subset[i,j]$ that is counted in the sum $S$ as one of the $j-i$ unit segments between $i$ and $j$.

It follows that
$$S={n+1\choose 3}\ .$$

Comment: @ Christian Blatler: Can you kindly explain "Conversely, for any three-element subset $\{i−1,l,j\}$ of $\{0,1,2,…,n\}$ we obtain an interval $[l,l+1]$ that is counted in the sum $S$" in detail?

Comment: @user64494: See my edit.